# How to change alternate list items to uppercase?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I need help in a school project that changes weak passwords so that they have equal number of uppercase and lower-case.

I have tried using a `for` loop to target each letter between `0` and half the length:

```
lengthhalf=length/2
if upcount != lowcount:
    str.lower(psswd[0:lengthhalf])

    print psswd
```

I have also targeted `lengthhalf+1` to `length` -

```
str.upper(psswd[lengthhalf+1::length])
```

It doesn't affect anything, though.

Comment: how do you want to change that passwords?

Comment: What cases are you supposed to be dealing with? Do you assume that the password initially starts all uppercase, all lowercase, some combination, including numbers/symbols...?

Comment: What do you want to happen when there's an unequal number of character in the password...or an odd number of letters...or no letters at all?

Comment: Note that making the first half of the password lower case and the last half upper case doesn't really improve password security, especially if the attacker is aware of this pattern. I'd be inclined to randomize the case of alpha chars in the password so that approximately half of them are upper case.

Comment: strings are immutable. You need to create a new string. `str.upper` returns a new uppercase version of the given string, it doesn't change the original.

Answer (score 1):

```
psswd = psswd[:lengthhalf].lower() + psswd[lengthhalf:].upper()
```

should do what you might have had in mind of doing.

I’m not sure what you want to do with odd-length “passwords”.

The issues in your code were:

- result of lower()/upper() was not assigned to anything, so it was lost
- some_list[begin::step], e.g. with two colons is valid, but the last value is the step not the end

Comment: This is fine if the password is all alpha, but it won't necessarily give a 50:50 ratio if the password contains non-alpha chars.

Answer (score 0):

There can de different interpretations of your spec but the following should do the trick by 1st splitting into two lists with alternate items, and then interleaving them back together again:

```
pwd = "absdef"
pwd = list(pwd)
l1 = pwd[::2]
l1 = [c.upper() for c in l1]
l2 = pwd[1::2]
l2 = [c.lower() for c in l2]
new_pwd_list = [val for pair in zip(l1, l2) for val in pair]
print "".join(new_pwd_list)
```

probably not going to handle non numeric characters in way that would makes sense but it gices you alternating case.